# How do I specify different background colours for different pages in Gridsome/vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, gridsome

How do I specify different background colours for different pages in Gridsome/vue.js? I've tried scoping the css but it won't work for the **body** or **html** selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html` and `body` are outside the application bounds. You will want to programatically control these elements.

Two simple avenues come to mind:

1. Use the [layouts](https://gridsome.org/docs/layouts/) approach which will work with or without scoped CSS.
2. Manipulate the body classList using [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can [pass props to layouts](https://gridsome.org/docs/layouts/#passing-props-to-layouts).
For example pass a prop like

```
<template>
  <Layout :background="white">
    <section>Add page content here</section>
  </Layout>
</template>
```

then write your css like

```
[background=white] section {
    background: #fff !important;
}
```